# Accessing dynamic content with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript, wikipedia-api

I'm working with wikipedia API and have a problem with the results I'm getting.

```
{"query":{
    "pages":{
        "48636":{
            "pageid":48636,
```

I don't know what the ID is going to be when I make the call, how do I access the 48636?

```
if gon.activateWiki
  $(gon.keywords).each (index, element) ->
    console.log element.name
    $.getJSON( 'http://sv.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions%7Clinks%7Cimages%7Ccategories&rvprop=content&titles=' + element.name + '&callback=?' , (data)  ->
      console.log data.query.pages
    )
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with JSON... you want to know how to access the unknown properties of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the trusty old Object.keys

```
firstKey = Object.keys(data.query.pages).shift()
lastKey = Object.keys(data.query.pages).pop()
nthKey = Object.keys(data.query.pages)[n-1]

firstPage = data.query.pages[firstKey]
lastPage = data.query.pages[lastKey]
nthPage = data.query.pages[n-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like an array:

```
console.log(data.query.pages["48636"]);
```

Update:

To get values from unknown property's of object you need to use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement. Or you can use `slice` method and transform your object to array:

```
var pages = Array.prototype.slice.call(data.query.pages);
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he doesn't know what the page Id will be, not that he can't access it.

Comment: @antyrat Hmm, I didn't seem to get that code to work. Am i missing something? It just gives me an empty object?